# Integrating a Maven project into Laravel application

Tags: php, scala, maven, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form in `Laravel 5.1`, I want to send my query to a `maven` based project and return the results back to my L5 app. The `maven` project is written in `Scala`. So, how can I integrate `maven` project into my `Laravel` app?

Any idea is welcomed, Thanks,

Comment: there are two possible route, the [`Scala` is a webservice](http://sysgears.com/articles/building-rest-service-with-scala/) - then you could use curl to communicate between the two. Or execute it locally using [php `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). tbh, you should post what approach you have tried and what problems you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `curl` to send my query to `Scala` API and sent the retrieved data to my View. There are couple of custom libraries to do this in Laravel in my case I used  [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl).